# Not able to build .net Solution using MSBuild plugin in Jenkins

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying first time to build .net solution project using MSBuild plugin.
I have setup custom workspace folder to my project.
I have installed and configured MSBuild.

I am not able to build successfully. Below is the console output in Jenkins:

```
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ESELServer\SEMCO_ESEL_SERVER.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from D:\BuildProjects\ESELWS
[ESELWS] $ cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe ESELServer\SEMCO_ESEL_SERVER.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What have you tried? can you build from command line? Can you build from command line using the same user that Jenkins runs under? Increase verbosity of MSBuild.exe output. use /verbosity:diag

Comment: Go to the build server. and manually call msbuild.exe "Mysolution.sln", and see what happens.  Jenkins isn't voodoo.  It usually downloads code from source-control and then does the msbuild.exe "Mysolution.sln" ......  You can manually see what happens.  Most common culprit is missing dependencies.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze,@granadaCoder I have tried with command prompt manually it builds. I tried with MSBuild.exe "MySolution.sln" it works fine. Now In Jenkins Job config I tried giving  "/verbosity:diag" in Command Line Arguments but its not giving any more info. Please note that I am creating a custom folder as workspace folder for my project. Every time I build it does a clean workspace folder and downloads the code again from repo. But its not building.

Comment: Did you run the build on the build server with the same user that the Jenkins service is running under?

Comment: @Peter Schuetze, Yes I run the build with same user as Jenkins service running under. When I keep the workspace folder under jenkins_home\jobs\<projName>\workspace its building with Jenkins but when I create a custom workspace its not building.

Comment: Do you really need a custom workspace?

Comment: @PeterSchuetze, Yes because My SVN path and Project name is too long without custom folder build is failing because filename exceeds OS limit.

Comment: Try enabling this two options from <br>